# Mobile Website Development Resources

Tags: iphone, android, html, mobile-website

I'm looking for some resources (online is good so I don't have to buy books, but books are ok) about mobile website development. I'm specifically targeting (in order) iPhone, Android, Blackberry. I'm proficient in HTML, and am getting into HTML5. I want to learn more about it in general, but specifically about using geolocation, detecting phone types, optimizing css, and a few other topics.  Does anyone have suggestions on where to look?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of good books from Apress that may be of interest:

[Beginning Smartphone Web Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/143022620X)

[Pro Smartphone Cross-Platform Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430228687)

Answer (score -1):

iPhone Human Interface Guidelines for Web Applications - 
http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/internetweb/conceptual/iPhoneWebAppHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html